# API call in useEffect returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, use-effect, use-state

I have a simple functional component, which includes a fetch to a JSON file stored locally.

I am trying to bring in the data from the JSON file, and whilst this should be a simple task, I have come across a problem.

My console log is showing two separate logs - one is an empty object, presumably from the `useState` definition and the second has the data from the fetch inside it.

Therefore, When I try to do anything with the data I'm fetching, `undefined` is being returned, So I can't use it. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not entirely sure what is going on here. I have tried `async/await` without success.

What am I missing ?

```
const Landing = () => {
    const [api, updateApi] = useState({});

    const getData = () => {
      fetch('data.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => updateApi({api: {data}}))
    }
    useEffect(() => {
      getData();
    }, []);

    console.log(api)
  
    return (
        <p>Hey!</p>
    )
}
```

Comment: "When I try to do anything with the data I'm fetching" — The only thing you are trying to do in that code is pass it to `console.log` and you said it "has the data from the fetch inside it" so it isn't `undefined`.

Comment: When you're setting your state with ```updateApi({'api' : {data}})``` why are you wrapping data in brackets? This makes your state look like this: ```api : { api : { data : {}}```.

Comment: @Quentin - thank you for your reply. 
I have two separate logs in my browser; the first is an empty object, just as I assigned it in useState; the second log is my fetched data. If I put it an endpoint, a name for example, then I get error codes saying that endpoint is undefined. If I refresh the page, then I get the endpoint rendered to the screen without issue. 

Does this clarify my problem at all?

Comment: @KevinZaworski - thank you for your reply. 
I have looked at the answers given and have updated my code to use 
```updateApi(data)``` instead, as I realise that I was using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to wrap the return within an if/else block, and return (for example a spinning circle) loading indicator. When it re-renders with the data from the api, it returns the desired representation of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Using async/await syntax you can put your `fetch` requests within the `useEffect` hook and set your state similar to how you are currently doing.

```js
export default function Landing() {
  const [api, updateApi] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("data.json");
      const data = await response.json();
      updateApi({ api: { data } });
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(api)}</div>;
}
```

If you initialise the state with `useState({})` then the value won't be `undefined`. If however you want to check for that before doing something then an if/else statement as suggested in another answer is suitable or if it is within the component `return` then a common pattern is `return <div>{api && JSON.stringify(api)}</div>;`.